# Is it possible to extract fixed effects from the general FGLS fixed effects model?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, plm

When I use `pggls` commmand for general FGLS estimators for panel data from R package `plm` model, `fixef` doesn't work. How to solve this problem?

```
fgls.fe <- pggls(Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df, model = "within")
summary(fgls.fe)

Error in UseMethod("fixef") : 
  no applicable method for 'fixef' applied to an object of class "c('pggls', 'panelmodel')"
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not only just about r programming but also lacks essential information for example about what r package is used and does not offer reproducible example.

Comment: There could be a statistical question behind: Are there fixed effects in the general FGLS models and how are they calculated? (The R package questions have been addressed by an edit; a reproducible example does not seem necessary.)

Comment: This model has individual effects and doesn't have time effects. When I use plm(y~x1+x2+x3, data=df, model="within") , "fixef" shows individual fixed effects. As I think, "fixef" support only for plm model(or OLS model). Are there any functions to extract individual fixed effetsc for GLS model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a blunder in the current version 2.2-3 of package `plm`:
Function `fixef.pggls` is not exported/registered.

This was fixed in a newer version of the package, available on CRAN.

(This question + answer should be moved to StackOverflow.)

Comment: it works! Thanks a lot!!